# Is there a function that combines the functions kbhit() and a getch()?

Tags: c++, c, function

I want function that combines the functions **kbhit()** and **getch()**.
In other words, I want when the program works, if I pressed on **'q'** key the program stops without has stopped temporarily in order to receive the character as does getch() function .
I want to combine between **kbhit()** advantage and **getch()** advantage .

I hope you understood my purpose .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kbhit` tells you whether there's a character waiting. `getch` will return the next character, wiating for one if it needs to. The only natural combination of the two that I can think of is one that will return a character if there is one, but won't wait if there isn't a character available. That's easy to do, given you already have `kbhit` and `getch`:

```
/* Returns a character from stdin, if there is one.
 * Otherwise, returns -1. */
int getch_nonblocking(void)
{
  return kbhit() ? getch() : -1;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought you were using curses. Apparently, you're using conio. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: It is _kbhit() and _getch()/_getche() form conio.h . And the algorithm above does not take special (function) keys into account.

Comment: Your above example works fine , but I don't understand it well, no problem

Comment: @Lion King: When reading a function key or an arrow key, getch() must be called twice; the first call returns 0 or 0xE0, and the second call returns the actual key code.

Comment: @Edwin, are you saying my function *should* take special keys into account? I'm not sure I agree. My function seems no worse than plain old `getch`.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: the case is when you press a function key or an arrow key (either with or without ctrl/shft/alt) you get as return value of getch either 0 or 0xE0. you must decide for yourself how to deal with that.  I myself would prefer that such an algorithm would take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your mention of `kbhit` and `getch`, you're probably using Windows. In that case, you might try [`GetKeyboardState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me a simple example please .

Comment: Is there a router down between you and the MSDN Library?

Comment: Basically, give it an array of 256 BYTEs before to get the state, then check every so often by using it again to see if any key states have changed from the original array.